# How to get windows terminal (wt.exe) to issue a command before entering the interactive mode?

Tags: conda, windows-terminal

Trying to get windows terminal to open a new terminal with a script being run. Specifically, `conda activate [env_name]` so that my profile is fully loaded. I saw the `-c` option, but I didn't seem to understand how to use it correctly.

Comment: example: wt cmd.exe /k dir

Comment: This is definitely an acceptable answer. I can choose it if you would like to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PowerShell perhaps you are referring to this:

```
pwsh -NoExit -Command ".\env\Scripts\activate"
```

You could also run multiple commands as such

```
pwsh -NoExit -Command "{Command1} '{Arg}'; & {Command2} '{Arg}'; & {Command3} '{Arg}'"
```

and so on

ex:

```
pwsh -NoExit -Command "cd '{Your Path}'; & mkdir 'new_folder'"
```

Notice the Single quotes around the arguments and semicolon separating the commands.

**For clarity**: The Curly Braces are not part of the command

Comment: The question was not about powershell, but the usual windows terminal

Comment: @LeBavarois as far as I know there isn't any -c command in wt so I figured he could run the command on powershell from wt I guess I opened my answer wrong